# In Civ 6 is there a notification log?

Tags: civilization-6

I would like to review each turns notifications. It seems other players have an icon for each turn, I do not have that icon. I just have dialog boxes that disappear before I can read them. Is there a log?

Comment: Civ V has a log you can look up but Civ VI does not.

Comment: A lot of youtubers and streamers use UI mods, so if you saw someone using such a log on YouTube or Twitch in Civ 6, it could be that it came from a UI mod. On YouTube they'll usually have the mods they're using in the description, on Twitch you can ask.